# where can i host my spring rest api and databse

Tags: spring, cordova, cloud, hosting

I am working on simple web/mobile app , I am done with the web version of it .

Spring for back-end
Html5 and angualr js for front end .
Mysql as database .

I have chosen phone gap for mobile app . it works locally fine with in my intranet .

now the quesiton is where I can host my spring app and database . When I work with some clients they provide putty access , so I can isntall tomcat java mysql on it so I can host the app there and I can start my tomcat .

I am very new to cloud platform . which package I need to chose to get access to a VM through putty . so I can install chosen softwares on it .

I searched through google , I found amazon provides a free tier and Heroku too . but I amnot sure how to work with them .

I need a free package initially to get to see if it works or not .

I am good at linux , so if I  get a shell I can play with it  . How to get this kind of hosting please suggest me more .

If you can help with some step by step guide links that would be great .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Red Hat's OpenShift.

> Develop, Host, and Scale Apps in the Cloud Red Hat's public cloud
>   application development and hosting platform automates the
>   provisioning, management and scaling of applications so that you can
>   focus on writing the code for your business, startup, or next big
>   idea.

https://www.openshift.com/features/